# Medical researcher trying to make a website to show interactive figures

Tags: html, web, cpanel

I am an Australian researcher that is investigating how long patients survive after being admitted to Intensive Care.

I have made some interactive figures that are saved as html objects on my desktop.

I've purchased a domain name and hosting for it and can upload individual figures through cPanel.

However, I would like to upload the 6 figures and have a title page users open when typing my website name in. On that title page would be 6 links to each of the figures.

Appreciate any guidance on where I should look to learn how to do this!

Comment: Welcome to the world of web development! W3Schools has some great tutorials for beginners (https://www.w3schools.com/), although if you just want to learn how to add a title and some links I'd recommend looking at h tags (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp) and a tags (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)